# How to validate phone number with a plus (+) sign and "(0)" by regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I see a lot of solutions to validate a phone number by Regex... But I want some characters in my phone number such as `+31(0)12` for example.

If you have string with the value `+31(0)12-1234567`. This is a correct notation of a phone number. How could you validate by using Regex?

I have tried this:

```
Regex phonePattern = new Regex(@"\+\d{3}?(\0)\d*\-\d*");
```

What do I wrong?

Other examples are:
`+31(0)6-12345678` or `+31(0)123-123456`

Comment: (0) is important too in your answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this issue too and found no duplicate here on SO to Regex a number with a plus `+` sign being a phone number.

Finally I formatted this Regex myself:

```
Regex phonePattern = new Regex(@"\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?([-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*)?((\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{2,4})(?:[-.x ]*(\d+))?)\s*");
```

[See it here on regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/K4F7KN/1)

This will match:

```
+nnnnnnnnnn
+nnn-nnn-nn
nnnnnnnnnnn
nnnn-nnnn-n
(nnn)nnnnnn
+(nnn)nnnnn
```

Comment: And specific a test if this is in the content: (0) ?

Comment: will this work if there's a space?

Answer (score 0):

should it be something like this: +\d{1,3}(0)\d*-\d*

your example isn't escaping the brackets around the zero and country codes can be 1 to 3 digits long.

Comment: @"+\d{1,3}(0)\d*-\d*" this gives an error message. I think you have to start with a \.